# choose which account to upload to

Tags: .net, google-drive-api

I have 4 gmail accounts, I use drive on 2 of them. I am logged into all 4 accounts at the same time on my local machine. My app needs to interact with only 1 of the 4 always. How do I specify which account to use in c# without any user interaction? It seems as if it uses the last account that was actually logged into. Maybe this cannot be done?

Current log in code:

```
UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
new ClientSecrets
{
    ClientId = "XXXXXXXXXXX",
    ClientSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
},
Scopes,
"checlark",
CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("CheClark.GoogleDrive.Auth.Store")).Result;

// Create the service.
var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "TimeKeeper",
});
```

Comment: Added my current login code.

Comment: Sorry, yes I am logged into all 4 in Chrome tabs.

Comment: No, it is a .Net console app. When I run the code it uploads a file and downloads as expected, but I seem to have no control over which of the 4 accounts it uses. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: So, how do I "tell" the object which drive account I want to use?

Comment: That is indeed correct! Not sure why it didn't seem that way yesterday. I guess new day, fresh look. I appreciate the help!

Comment: I removed my other comments, and converted the one that mattered into an answer. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to target a specific google drive, set the 3rd argument to AuthorizeAsync(), which specifies the user account. In your example, this is "checlark".

[See this doc page for the full signature of the `AuthorizeAsync()` function.](http://contrib.google-api-dotnet-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.8.2/documentation/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Auth_1_1OAuth2_1_1GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.html#a95045cb55eeb08fadd27b33e0193327c)